# Как корректно подать данные в json-файл?

Tags: python, json

Код:

```
question = str(question) + ' ->'

answer = str(answer) + ' ###'

lines = json.dumps({'prompt:Q': question,'completion': answer}, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Что получаю:

```
"{\"prompt:Q\": \"Hi ->\", \"completion\": \"Ola ###\"}"
```

Что хочу получить:

```
{"prompt":"Q: Hi ->","completion":" Ola ###"}
```

Мне нужно избавиться от кавычек перед и после фигурных скобок + от бэкслеша \

Весь код write_json.py

```
import json
import os
from pathlib import Path


# Название файла
json_filename = 'dataset.json'

# Указываем ту же директорию, откуда запускается скрипт
path = str(Path(__file__).with_name(json_filename))

if not os.path.isfile(path):
    with open(path, "w+") as f:
        f.write('start\n')


# Функция записи сообщений в json файл.
def write_messages(question, answer):
    lines = json.dump({'prompt:Q': question,'completion': answer},    ensure_ascii=False) # Подготавливаем строку json


    # Записываем новую строку в файл
    with open(path, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
        json.dump(lines, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
        f.write("\n")


В json поступает следующая информация:

{
  "prompt": "Q: ТЕКСТ ->",
  "completion": " ТЕКСТ ###"
}

А хотелось бы получить: 

{"prompt": "Q: ТЕКСТ ->","completion": " ТЕКСТ ###"}
```

Comment: Покажите как в файл записываете. Запись просто через `file.write(lines)` должна быть, или через json.dump без промежуточного dumps. Такое впечатление, что вы делаете dumps, а потом результат еще раз в json преобразовываете при записи в файл через dump.

Comment: @insolor впервые пользуюсь stackoverflow, как к комментарию код прикрепить не знаю, так что прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Ну да, как я и думал. Просто делайте `lines = {'prompt:Q': question,'completion': answer}`, потом `json.dump(lines, ...)`. dumps и dump - это фактически одно и то же действие, просто одно в строку сохраняет json, второе в файл. Получается, что вы два раза данные в json преобразовываете.

Comment: @insolor Огромная благодарность! Уже все нервы на пределе, а как мне записывать данные в одну строчку? Как здесь: {"prompt":"Q: Hi ->","completion":" Ola ###"}? И, если не трудно, подскажите материалы, книги, где я бы мог закрепить знания в работе с json?

Comment: Что именно в одну строчку? Никакие особенные материалы не нужны, просто почитайте документацию по модулю json.

Comment: @insolor Добавил к вопросу. Буду читать документацию. Если эти записи идентичны, значит не буду ничего менять. Дело в том, что есть шаблон по заполнению json файла, сейчас отправлю в текущем виде, проверю, не будет ли ругаться программа

Comment: Если нужно чтобы json в одну строку писался, а не на несколько строк с отступами, нужно indent=2 убрать (это как раз настройка размера отступов, если убрать, то будет просто в одну строку)

Comment: @insolor Благодарю! Без вас я бы еще долго мучился. Пойду читать документацию..